# Using particles.js with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, particles.js

I refered to [react-particles npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-particles) and made one simple particle example and it works well. But when I try to implement other example using my draft, don't know how to apply it to mine. 
I want to implement [this](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/#default) with React. I expected it would work it I just copy and paste json of example. But it deosn't work. I guess it's because format of particles *options* is different. Can you let me know how can I apply below json file to my draft??

**my draft:** 
works well

```
import { useCallback } from "react";
import Particles from "react-particles";
import { loadFull } from "tsparticles";

export default function App() {
  const particlesInit = useCallback(async (engine) => {
    console.log(engine);
  }, []);

  const particlesLoaded = useCallback(async (container) => {
    await console.log(container);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Particles
      id="tsparticles"
      init={particlesInit}
      loaded={particlesLoaded}
      options={{
        background: {
          color: {
            value: "#0d47a1"
          }
        },
        fpsLimit: 120,
        interactivity: {
          events: {
            onClick: {
              enable: true,
              mode: "push"
            },
            onHover: {
              enable: true,
              mode: "repulse"
            },
            resize: true
          },
          modes: {
            push: {
              quantity: 4
            },
            repulse: {
              distance: 200,
              duration: 0.4
            }
          }
        },
        particles: {
          color: {
            value: "#ffffff"
          },
          links: {
            color: "#ffffff",
            distance: 150,
            enable: true,
            opacity: 0.5,
            width: 1
          },
          collisions: {
            enable: true
          },
          move: {
            direction: "none",
            enable: true,
            outModes: {
              default: "bounce"
            },
            random: false,
            speed: 6,
            straight: false
          },
          number: {
            density: {
              enable: true,
              area: 800
            },
            value: 80
          },
          opacity: {
            value: 0.5
          },
          shape: {
            type: "circle"
          },
          size: {
            value: { min: 1, max: 5 }
          }
        },
        detectRetina: true
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/particles-js-react-95dk5k?file=/src/App.js)

**json :**

```
{
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 80,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 3,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "repulse"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 400,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
}
```

**failed** 
just copied and pasted json to *options* but it doesn't work

```
import { useCallback } from "react";
import Particles from "react-particles";
import { loadFull } from "tsparticles";

export default function App() {
  const particlesInit = useCallback(async (engine) => {
    console.log(engine);
  }, []);

  const particlesLoaded = useCallback(async (container) => {
    await console.log(container);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Particles
      id="tsparticles"
      init={particlesInit}
      loaded={particlesLoaded}
      options={{
        "particles": {
          "number": {
            "value": 80,
            "density": {
              "enable": true,
              "value_area": 800
            }
          },
          "color": {
            "value": "#ffffff"
          },
          "shape": {
            "type": "circle",
            "stroke": {
              "width": 0,
              "color": "#000000"
            },
            "polygon": {
              "nb_sides": 5
            },
            "image": {
              "src": "img/github.svg",
              "width": 100,
              "height": 100
            }
          },
          "opacity": {
            "value": 0.5,
            "random": false,
            "anim": {
              "enable": false,
              "speed": 1,
              "opacity_min": 0.1,
              "sync": false
            }
          },
          "size": {
            "value": 3,
            "random": true,
            "anim": {
              "enable": false,
              "speed": 40,
              "size_min": 0.1,
              "sync": false
            }
          },
          "line_linked": {
            "enable": true,
            "distance": 150,
            "color": "#ffffff",
            "opacity": 0.4,
            "width": 1
          },
          "move": {
            "enable": true,
            "speed": 6,
            "direction": "none",
            "random": false,
            "straight": false,
            "out_mode": "out",
            "bounce": false,
            "attract": {
              "enable": false,
              "rotateX": 600,
              "rotateY": 1200
            }
          }
        },
        "interactivity": {
          "detect_on": "canvas",
          "events": {
            "onhover": {
              "enable": true,
              "mode": "repulse"
            },
            "onclick": {
              "enable": true,
              "mode": "push"
            },
            "resize": true
          },
          "modes": {
            "grab": {
              "distance": 400,
              "line_linked": {
                "opacity": 1
              }
            },
            "bubble": {
              "distance": 400,
              "size": 40,
              "duration": 2,
              "opacity": 8,
              "speed": 3
            },
            "repulse": {
              "distance": 200,
              "duration": 0.4
            },
            "push": {
              "particles_nb": 4
            },
            "remove": {
              "particles_nb": 2
            }
          }
        },
        "retina_detect": true
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: There is no error in console, so what's the issue? *"It doesn't work"* is not clear

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply. If you enter the codesandbox I linked to, can see that particles works fine. But when you look at the failed code where I replaced the options with a json file, there are no particles and a blank screen is displayed.

Comment: I suggest editing the **title** (of this question) to explicitly and shortly describe the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration is correct. But it needs the background [color](https://particles.js.org/docs/classes/tsParticles_Engine.Options_Classes_Background_Background.Background.html#color) configuration, and you will see it.

> This `color` is set to canvas style `background-color` property, if this property is not set the background will be transparent.

```js
background: {
  color: {
    value: '#b61924',
  },
},
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76669242-jyzjcj?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: It's now working as I expected. Thank you very much for your reply!